# Reference variables in expressions in Ansible/Jinja

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to figure out how I can reference a dictionary item in a variable based on another variable. For example:

`{{ myVariable.someItem.someVariableItem.someOtherItem }}`

Essentially, `myVariable` is (obviously) a variable, but I want the item `someVariableItem` to be set elsewhere. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible.

```
"{{ myVariable.someItem[someVariableItem].someOtherItem }}"
```

For example the play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_variable_item: item_z
    my_dict:
      item_x:
        other_item_a: 1
      item_y:
        other_item_b: 2
      item_z:
        other_item_c: 3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: '{{ my_dict[my_variable_item].other_item_c }}'
```

gives

```
"msg": "3"
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly, and tested on Ansible 2.0 and 2.8.5 on MacOS with Python 3.7 and 2.8.5 with Python 2.7. I'm not sure why it's not working on my RHEL environment though.